# Typeclass method which returns another typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have this task in which I have to define 2 typeclasses in Haskell. One is simple - it implements Ord and has one method which converts given type to an int. Something like this:

```
class (Ord a) => Id a where
  toInt :: a -> Int
```

But then I have another typeclass *HasId* which has a method *getId*. This method should return *Id* typeclass. So I wrote something like this:

```
class HasId a where
  getId :: a -> Id a
```

And I get an error I don't know how to solve.

```
• Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
• In the class declaration for ‘HasId’
 |
 | class (Int a) => HasId a where     |        ^^^^^

• Expected a type, but ‘Id a’ has kind ‘Constraint’
• In the type signature: getId :: a -> Id a
  In the class declaration for ‘HasId’
 |
 |  getId :: a -> Id a     |
```

Can somebody tell me how can I return typeclass in another's typeclass method? 
Should I implement some instance of *Id* typeclass at first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to understand that a Haskell `class` is very different from a class in OO languages. It's a *type class*, i.e. it “groups together a collection of types”, whereas an OO class groups together a collection of *values*. IOW, an OO class *is* a type (containing values), but a Haskell class is rather something like a type *of types*, as it were.

Now, a function/method always takes values as argument and gives back values as results. But it can't give you back a type, nor a “value of a typeclass” because there's no such thing.

Instead, the way to use type classes is this: you write a *polymorphic function*, i.e. a function that accepts or yields some value of unspecified type. That's what *type variables* are there for. Normally, a polymorphic signature means that the function can deal with values of *any* type, like with

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

which takes a list and doesn't care what type its elements have. But then you say that you do *care a bit* what types are used, namely, you require that they are in the class. That's a *constraint*, and it's written with the `=>` notation. `toInt` actually has the signature (automatically generated by the class declaration)

```
toInt :: Id a => a -> Int
```

Frankly, I doubt that this is really what you want. If all you can do with an `Id a` is converting it to an `Int`, then the result effectively *is* an `Int` (just with a type-annotation which indicates what kind of object this Id belongs to), regardless of the `a` parameter. So instead of the `Id` class, you should consider having an *`Id` type*

```
newtype Id' a = Id {toInt :: Int}  -- The prime ' symbol has no particular meaning,
                                   -- I just use it for disambiguation.
```

Then, you have the more sensible type

```
toInt :: Id' a -> Int
```

without needing any constraints.

`newtype` is much more similar to a OO class, in that it actually defines a concrete type which has values you can pass around.

The `getId` method is also a constrained-polymorphic function, that can take something which “has an `Id`” and gives you back that Id. In this case, a class makes sense (because you can have different data structure that may store their Ids in different ways). This would now actually be

```
class HasId a where
  getId :: a -> Id' a
```

As per [Welperooni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908163/745903), it is indeed also conveivable to define `HasId` using your original `Id` class, just it doesn't really make much sense. `Id` is the *class of all types which can be used as identifyers*. You could express that `getId` can yield an Id of  any such type:

```
class HasId a where
  getId :: Id b => a -> b
```

Note that the result-Id type is now completely independent of the type of object whose Id you want to calculate. `b` can always be *any* Id-type. As I said this doesn't make sense: why would you need a whole lot of different types that represent Ids, but require all the `HasId` types to support *all of them*?

In fact this cannot be implemented as it stands, because there's no mechanism that allows you to *generate* an Id of arbitrary `Id` type. This would require an additional method

```
class Id a where
  toInt :: a -> Int
  fromInt :: Int -> a
```

and now you could do

```
class HasId a where
  getId :: Id b => a -> b

data SomeObj { objName :: String
             , objId :: Int }

instance HasId SomeObj where
  getId (SomeObj _ i) = fromInt i
```

However, if you require that any `Id` type is convertible both from and to `Int`, then these types *must* be isomorphic to `Int` itself. Therefore, the `newtype Id' a` approach is almost certainly better.

Comment: Thank you for your expanded answer! Really appreciate your help. I actually need it for the test tomorrow so once again thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You declared the return value to be a HKT `Id a`, but what you wanted is another type, constrained by the typeclass `Id`.

What you need is not `getId :: a -> Id a`, but `getId :: Id b => a -> b`

Comment: This may _typecheck_, but I doubt that it actually _works_. The `Id` class as it's given in the question makes `getId :: Id b => a -> b` basically impossible to implement.